# REGEX Python Pattern works individually, but doesn't return matches when I run the whole thing

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following pattern to retrieve matches in dictionaries;

logdata = file.read()

```
    pattern="""

    (?P<host>[\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3})        
    (?P<user_name>-\s*(.*?)\s*)                                     
    (?P<time>\[(.*?)\])                                               
    (?P<request>\"(.*?)\")  

    """

    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
        print(item.groupdict())
```

When I run this, I get ZERO matches. But when I run the each group separately I am getting individual matches, like;

```
 (?P<host>[\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3})
```

(this is returning matches)

Example TEXT: 146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you expect one match per line, read one line at a time and `re.match` on it. Reading the entire file into memory if you don't need to is wasteful and complicates the question.

Comment: Also, the regex is hugely ambiguous. Don't use `.*?` when you mean `[^"]*` etc.

Comment: @tripleee what's ambiguous about using a _non-greedy match all_? The difference, from a readability point of view, is simply that one style tells you what character comes next BEFORE it's supposed to appear in the string and the other tells you WHEN it's supposed to appear in the string. Functionally they mean the same thing `(.*?X) === ([^X]*X)`. Surely one could argue that using the `^` operator is more ambiguous as it has more than one meaning...

Comment: See the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for a simple example. Less specific wildcards force the engine to backtrack needlessly when you don't way what you mean.

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful? Consider voting/accepting an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

When you add the patterns together you need to allow the cursor to advance from one match to the next without gaps adding .*? or other optional quantifiers. This should do the trick:

```
(?P<host>[\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}).*?(?P<user_name>-\s*(.*?)\s+).*?(?P<time>\[(.*?)\]).*?(?P<request>\"(.*?)\")
```

[PCRE Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lbc2Zh/1)

I had to slightly adjust the subpattern used to detect the user name because it was not using a proper end anchor, e.g. the space after it. Though, the named capture group for the username has the dash prefix. You may want to use $3 instead but maybe you actually want the prefix.

A more optimized pattern could look like this:

```
(?P<host>[\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3})\s+-\s+(?P<user_name>.*?)\s+\[(?P<time>.*?)\]\s+\"(?P<request>[^"]+)\"
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/lbc2Zh/2)

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes with using re.VERBOSE. When using this, any whitespace not preceded by a backslash is eliminated therefore in your original pattern, it was not returning anything due to the whitespace before and after the dashes, square brackets, etc.

The other issue was coming from having groups within the named groups. I changed the regex so that the named groups point towards the required strings.

Try the code below. It works for the example shown.

```
pattern="""

    (?P<host>[\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3})\ -\ 
    (?P<user_name>\s*.*?\s*)
    \ \[(?P<time>.*?)\]\ 
    \"(?P<request>.*?)\"

    """

    for item in re.finditer(pattern,logdata,re.VERBOSE):
        print(item.groupdict())
```

Side note:

Additional reading on VERBOSE: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/verbose-in-python-regex/

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is you are not caring the spaces between the words.
Just update the pattern like below.

```
pattern="""

    (?P<host>[\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3}[\.][\d]{1,3})
    \s*
    (?P<user_name>-\s*(.*?)\s*)
    \s*
    (?P<time>\[(.*?)\])
    \s*
    (?P<request>\"(.*?)\")  

"""
```

Comment: Surely those should be `\s+`

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions**

1. Search string is pre-formatted and will always have the same format:

   ```
    HOST - USER [TIME_STAMP] "POST_TYPE" MISC_DATA
   ```
2. Only one search string is given at a time

**Input**

```
146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622
```

**RegEx**

```
___REGEX [1]___

// Short form capture of all relevant data

([\d\.]*) - (.*?) \[(.*?)\] \"(.*?)\"
([\d\.]*)                                : First capture group; catch any number or "."
          -                              : Spacer between first and second capture group
            (.*?)                        : Second capture group; non-greedy capture until next space {space is outside of group - we don't want to capture it}
                  \[                     : Spacer between second and third capture group
                    (.*?)                : Third capture group; non-greedy capture until next closing square bracket {bracket is outside of group - we don't want to capture it}
                         \] \"           : Spacer between third and fourth capture group
                              (.*?)      : Fourth capture group; non-greedy capture until closing double quote {double quote is outside of group - we don't want to capture it}
                                   \"    : Closing double quote; end of match


___REGEX [2]___

// Same as [1] BUT with group names

(?P<host>[\d\.]*) - (?P<user_name>.*?) \[(?P<time>.*?)\] \"(?P<request>.*?)\"


___REGEX [3]___

// A more strict version of [1]

((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}) - (.*?) \[(.*?)\] \"(.*?)\"
(                                                        : Start of first capture group
 (?:                                                     : Start of non-capturing group
    \d{1,3}\.                                            : Match any number 1 to 3 times followed by a "."
             ){3}                                        : End capture group and repeat capture group 3 times
                 \d{1,3}                                 : Match any number 1 to 3 times
                        ) - (.*?) \[(.*?)\] \"(.*?)\"    : Rest of pattern from [1]


___REGEX [4]___

// Similar to [3] BUT with lookaheads

((?:\d{1,3}\.?(?=.| )){4}) - (.*?) \[(.*?)\] \"(.*?)\"

___REGEX [5]___

// Similar to [3] BUT matching initial group with [\D] instead of [\. ]

((?:\d{1,3}\D){4})- (.*?) \[(.*?)\] \"(.*?)\"
```

**Example**

```
import re

regex    = r"([\d\.]*) - (.*?) \[(.*?)\] \"(.*?)\""
test_str = """146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622"""
matches  = re.findall(regex, test_str)

// RESULT: matches == [(
               '146.204.224.152',
               'feest6811',
               '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700',
               'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'
           )]
```